# Crossfiltering in Folium Maps

Tags: python, geospatial, crossfilter, folium

I have created an interactive folium map with python containing 2 layers. One layer displays the stores of our company and the other layer displays the postal codes. Each store has assigned postal codes to it. I have added tooltips, colors, etc but I would also like to add some cross-filtering functionality. E.g. Clicking a specific store, revealing only the postal codes that are assigned to that store.

Is something like that possible?